# How to input some data into a website and get the output from the html table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, Recently I've been trying to get some marks from a result website (http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.htm) for my school results.... My friends challenged me to get his marks for which I only know his DOB and not his Register Number.. How do I make a Python program to solve this by trying to input register numbers from a predefined range(I know his DOB, btw)?

I tried using requests, but it doesn't allow me to enter the register and DOB..

Comment: Show some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a POST request with the following format after pushing the Submit button:

```
https://dge3.tn.nic.in/plusone/plusoneapi/marks/{registration number}/{DOB}
```

Sample (with 112231 as `registration number` and `01-01-2000` as DOB.

```
https://dge3.tn.nic.in/plusone/plusoneapi/marks/112231/01-01-2000
```

You can then iterate over different registration numbers with a predefined array.
**Note:** it has to be a POST request, not a regular GET request.

You probably have to do something like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DOB = '01-01-2000'
REGISTRATION_NUMBERS = ['1','2']

for reg_number in REGISTRATION_NUMBERS:
    result = requests.post(f"https://dge3.tn.nic.in/plusone/plusoneapi/marks/{reg_number}/{DOB}")

    content = result.content
    print(content)
    ## BeautifulSoup logic
```

I don't know if that request is providing you the information you need, I don't have valid registration numbers combined with the correct date of birth, so I cannot really test it...

**Update 2019-07-09:**
Since you said the page is not working anymore and the website changed, I took a look.
It seems that some things have changed you now have to make a post request to `http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.asp`. The fields 'regno', 'dob' and 'B1' (optional?) should be send as x-www-form-urlencoded.

Since that will return an 'Access Denied' you should set the 'Referer'-header to 'http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.htm'. so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DOB = '23-10-2002'
REGISTRATION_NUMBERS = ['5709360']

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'Referer': 'http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.htm'})

for reg_number in REGISTRATION_NUMBERS:
    post_data = {'regno': reg_number, 'dob': DOB}
    result = requests.post(f"http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.asp", data=post_data, headers=headers)

    content = result.content
    print(content)
    ## BeautifulSoup logic
```

Tested it myself successfully now you've provided a valid DOB and registration number.

Comment: Umm.. It seems that url which you gave got taken down.. The one which works (for a normal check) is http://tnresults.nic.in/rgnfs.htm instead of https://dge1.tn.nic.in/hscfy.html ... might need some help here.. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer after taking a quick look. Hope it works!

Comment: You may use these values for testing: register number = 5709360 and dob = 23-10-2002

Comment: b"Pl provide proper registration Number<p></p><a  data-rel='external' class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left' href='rgnfs.htm' class='dontprintme' data-ajax='false' >Back</a>"

Comment: Updated my answer, should send the form along with the data of the request